# Built in datatype definitions

Tags: types, xsd, built-in

Can I find the xsd definitions for the builtin datatypes anywhere, or are they not defined using xsd?

For example, I would guess that the xs:boolean datatype would be defined something like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="boolean">
    <xs:restriction>
      <xs:pattern value="true|false|0|1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

(Since according to the specification, http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean, boolean can have one of the values 'true', 'false', '0' or '1'.)

But I cant find the schema-specification for the builtin datatypes.

Again, on http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2 there is "A Schema for Datatype Definitions", but to me this scema doesen't really define much. Again, the boolean type is defined like this in that schema:

```
<xs:simpleType name="boolean" id="boolean">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <hfp:hasFacet name="pattern"/>
        <hfp:hasFacet name="whiteSpace"/>
        <hfp:hasProperty name="ordered" value="false"/>
        <hfp:hasProperty name="bounded" value="false"/>
        <hfp:hasProperty name="cardinality" value="finite"/>
        <hfp:hasProperty name="numeric" value="false"/>
      </xs:appinfo>
      <xs:documentation source="http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean"/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:anySimpleType">
      <xs:whiteSpace fixed="true" value="collapse" id="boolean.whiteSpace"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

but this only gives a whiteSpace restriction.
The same applies to all other datatypes as well, so I don't understand how this schema defines the datatypes properly.

So again, if there is a schema which defines the builtin datatypes, where can I find it?
...or am I missunderstanding something here?

Hope my question is clear enough :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  you can find some approximations, but you cannot find the normative definitions of the built-in types of XSD, because (as you suspected) they are not normatively defined using XSD.

Longer answer:  The primitive datatypes, including xsd:boolean, form the foundation of the type system; it is not possible even in principle for there to be an XSD declaration for any primitive type.  (The term 'primitive' is just a name we give to those things in a system which must be defined outside of the system, usually in prose, and not inside the system.)

In general terms, the reason is simple:  XSD simple-type declarations define new types in terms of the existing primitives -- so the primitives must already be known by any XSD processor, before it can process any XSD type definitions.  Any attempt to define the primitives using XSD would (a) make the types so defined be, by definition, derived types instead of primitives, and (b) lead to an infinite regress.  In more concrete terms:  we can enumerate the lexical forms 'true', 'false, '1', and '0', as you show -- but xsd:enumeration is defined only as a way of restricting the value space of some base type (missing in your example) by enumerating selected values in the value space of that base type.  But the primitives can't be defined that way; for formal purposes, they do have a base type (xsd:anySimpleType in XSD 1.0, xsd:anyAtomicType in XSD 1.1), but the value space of anyAtomicType is defined (in prose) as the union of the value spaces of all current and future primitive types.  The nature of the primitive types' value spaces and the nature of the mapping from lexical space to value space cannot be defined in XSD; they must be given in prose.  (For example:  your enumeration lists the values of boolean; how might one go about defining the lexical space for xsd:anyURI?  How would you specify that '1' and 'true' both denote the same value, and that '0' and 'false' denote the other value?

Some of the built-in types -- specifically, all the ordinary (non-primitive) built-ins -- could, in principle, be declared in XSD syntax .  But since processors are required to have in-built knowledge of the built-in types, providing an actual XSD declaration for them cannot lead to useful results:  at best the declarations you provide will be ignored as unnecessary and redundant; a processor might also choose to raise an error at what it might see as an attempt to provide a second declaration for an already declared type.  (A cleaner story about a kernel and standard library could have avoided that problem, but the XSD wg did not provide a clean story in 1.0, and backward-compatibility concerns meant the wg was unable to clean up the resulting mess in 1.1.)

In the XSD 1.0 [schema for schema documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#schema) you'll find approximations of XSD declarations for all the built-ins; you may find the declarations for the non-primitives less unsatisfactory than those for the primitives.  For the reasons mentioned above, all these declarations were moved out of the schema for schema documents in XSD 1.1, into  two separate pseudo-schema documents, one for the [primitive datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#sec-prim-nxsd) and one for the [ordinary built-in datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#drvd.nxsd).